# How to convert command parameters into optional ones?

Tags: macros, xparse

LaTeX allows the use of optional parameters. Sometimes one wants to *rewrite* a command by making certain parameters optional:

```
\newcommand{\foo}[2]{
    #some commands
}
```

to:

```
\newcommand{\foo}[2][a]{
    #some commands
}
```

As far as I know, overloading is not supported in LaTeX thus making certain parameters optional cannot be done with low coupeling because calls to the method `\foo{a}{b}` must be converted to `\foo[a]{b}`. One cannot define the helper method `\foo{}{}` such that the package is backwards compatible.

I'm wondering what tools are available to rewrite command calls automatically, or macros to solve this problem elegantly.

Comment: Let me try guessing: you have a command `\foo` and you'd like that the calls `\foo{a}{b}` and `\foo[a]{b}` do the same?

Comment: Indeed. So one argument is "optionalized"...

Comment: Then my advice is “don't”. What would `\foo{b}` mean?

Comment: @CommuSoft: Both versions should coexist peacefully in the same document?

Comment: Well it's a package that is defined for multiple projects. But after some time, one realizes the command is nearly always invoked with the same (first) argument...

Comment: @CommuSoft: If it is not too much work, I would either `search and replace` or provide a new version, with a key value syntax. Of course it is possible to use `\foo[]{}` and `\foo{}{}`, but as egreg stated: `foo{}` is not recognized as being `\foo[default value]{}` and then treated as `foo{}{}` with an empty second argument. There might be some solution to this, but I can't provide it, I am too bad in such more sophisticated look-ahead-token - stuff ;-)

Comment: Why don't you just define `\newcommand\Foo[2][a]{\foo{#1}{#2}}`? Now `\Foo{b}` is the same as `\foo{a}{b}`. I'm assuming that `\foo` is some generic latex command and you just want a shortcut for the first argument...

Comment: @CommuSoft I'd define a new command `\Foo{a}{b}` and redefine `\foo[a]{b}` to expand to `\Foo{a}{b}` together with a warning that the command is deprecated and will be removed from the package eventually. I'd also remove the description of `\foo` in favor of `\Foo` from the package's manual

Comment: It is possible to do this but it is bad latex syntax. Latex always uses `[]` for optional arguments.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if I understand well your question. IMHO you want to write

```
\foo {a}{b} ... % The macro \foo with two parameters will be invoked
\foo {a}    ... % Another variant of the macro \foo with one parameter.
                % May be the missing parameter is substituted by default here
```

My solution is, unfortunately, not expandable. The processing of scanning the braces is done at main processor level. But you can define the variants of \foo from zero to nine parameters:

```
% NormalTeXsyntaxOn

\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\def\sdef#1{\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname}

\newcount\tmpnum
\def\foo{\def\fooC{}\tmpnum=0\futurelet\next\fooA}
\def\fooA{\ifx\next\bgroup \expandafter\fooB\else
   \csname foo\the\tmpnum\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter\fooC\fi}
\def\fooB#1{\addto\fooC{{#1}}\advance\tmpnum by1\futurelet\next\fooA}

\sdef{foo0}{foo without parameters}
\sdef{foo1}#1{foo with one parameter "#1"}
\sdef{foo2}#1#2{foo with two parameters "#1" and "#2"}
\sdef{foo3}#1#2#3{foo with three parameters "#1", "#2" and "#3"}
\sdef{foo4}#1#2#3#4{foo with four parameters "#1", "#2", "#3" and "#4"}

\foo ...
\foo {a} ...         
\foo {a}{b} ...         
\foo {a}{b}{c} ...      
\foo {a}{b}{c}{d} ...   
\foo {a}{b}{c}{d}{f} ...

% NormalTeXsyntaxOff
```

**Edit** As an example the code above is packed to `\multidef` and the usage of the macro with three parameters with default values is shown:

```
\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\def\ssdef#1{\expandafter\def\csname\string#1\endcsname}
\newcount\tmpnum
\def\multidef#1{%
  \def#1{\def\tmpparam{}\tmpnum=0
         \expandafter\futurelet\expandafter\next\csname\string#1-A\endcsname}%
  \ssdef{#1-A}{\ifx\next\bgroup \csname\string#1-B\expandafter\endcsname\else
      \csname \string#1\the\tmpnum\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endcsname
      \expandafter\tmpparam\fi}%
  \ssdef{#1-B}##1{\addto\tmpparam{{##1}}\advance\tmpnum by1
      \expandafter\futurelet\expandafter\next\csname\string#1-A\endcsname}%
}
\multidef\foo  % the \foo macro with various numbers of parameters is defined here
\ssdef{\foo0}{\fooNormal{defaultA}{defaultB}{defaultC}}
\ssdef{\foo1}#1{\fooNormal{defaultA}{defaultB}{#1}}
\ssdef{\foo2}#1#2{\fooNormal{defaulA}{#1}{#2}}
\ssdef{\foo3}{\fooNormal}
\def\fooNormal#1#2#3{foo invoked: param1=#1, param2=#2, param3=#3}

Test:
\foo ...            % does: \fooNormal{defaultA}{defaultB}{defaultC}
\foo {a} ...        % does: \fooNormal{defaultA}{defaultB}{a}
\foo {a}{b} ...     % does: \fooNormal{defaultA}{a}{b}
\foo {a}{b}{c} ...  % does: \fooNormal{a}{b}{c}
```

Is it what do you want?